# Background color resetting when toggling class from JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am designing a sidebar and I have two classes: sidebar-wrapper-visible and "-"-invisible. When I click the hamburger menu, it toggles off sidebar-wrapper-visible and toggles on sidebar-wrapper-invisible class. I have the background color set as black but when the sidebar collapses, it turns white for a split second which is really hurting my eyes.

```
.sidebar-wrapper-invisible {
  background-color:wheat;
  width:0px;
  transition:all 0.25s;
}

.sidebar-wrapper-visible {
  background-color:wheat;
  width:59px;
  height:100%;
  transition:all 0.25s;
}
```

Javascript:

```
const sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
const menuBtn = document.getElementById('menuBtn');
const hambar = document.getElementById('hambar');


class Sidebar {
  closeHamburgerMenu() {
    hambar.classList.toggle('hambar-open');
  };

  enableSidebar() {
    sidebar.classList.toggle('sidebar-wrapper-invisible');
    sidebar.classList.toggle('sidebar-wrapper-visible');
  }
}
```

[For reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmNzt.gif)

Comment: Could you add your HTML as well?

Comment: First of all, please provide a proper [mre] of the issue, when asking this kind of question.

Comment: Second - you should rather not do this by manipulating the width of the sidebar element. Use a [`transform()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate) translation to move it out of the viewport in its default state, and then transition that translation to 0.

Comment: And you should also not use two classes that you switch exclusively. Rather, write one `.sidebar-wrapper` rule, to set the general styling - and then an _additional_ one with selector `.sidebar-wrapper.open`, via which you apply the formatting for the opened state. And then you just toggle that `open` class on and off. Then you don't need the rather ugly repetition of styles in _both_ classes (like you currently have, with the background-color.)

Comment: And finally, the cherry-on-top - you can do the whole thing by toggling only _one_ class on _one_ element. Toggle a class `sidebar-open` on the `html` element - and then in your stylesheet, write rules `html.sidebar-open #hambar {}`, `html.sidebar-open #sidebar {}`, `html.sidebar-open #menuBtn {}` to apply the desired styling to those elements, when the sidebar is opened.